# Using shoulda macros with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macros, rspec, shoulda

I'm trying to use the shoulda macros within RSpec and am having some problems.

I've done the following:

spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'shoulda/active_record/macros'

Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
    ...
    config.include(Shoulda::ActiveRecord::Macros, :type => :model)
```

spec/models/foo_spec.rb:

```
describe Foo do
    it { should_have_instance_methods( :save ) } # just for example
end
```

Which gives me a failure with:

`undefined method 'get_options!' for #<Spec::Rails::Example::ModelExampleGroup::Subclass_1:0xb714046c>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just syntax:

not:

```
it { should_have_instance_methods( :save ) }
```

but

```
it { should have_instance_methods( :save ) }
```

(note the underscores)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about the integration with RSpec, but did you wrap the chunk where you call should_have_instance_methods in a context?  IIRC all should statements from shoulda require a context wrapped around them.